# How to calculate each child div height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

How calculate height and width of child DIVs.

I want to calculate height and width of each child DIV then compare its width and height. If Width is greater then Height then add  **class1** or height is greater then width then add **class2**. And width is equal to height then add **class3**

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.grid').children().each(function(item) {
    var divHeight = 0;
    var divWidth = 0;
    divHeight = $('.grid-item').height();
    divWidth = $('.grid-item').width();
    console.log(divWidth);
    console.log(divHeight);
    //check if child div's width is greater then height then add some class
    if ($(this).width() > $(this).height()) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('class1')) {
        $(this).removeClass('class1');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('class1');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* ---- grid ---- */

h1 {
  text-align: center
}

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - masonry layout mode</h1>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have console errors

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, Thanks for edit man!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if children of `class="grid"` is always `class="grid-item"` better use selector as `$('.grid-item')`

- also use `.outerHeight()` and `.outerWidth()` method to calculate the exact height and width with margins

```js
$('.grid-item').each(function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    let divHeight = parseFloat($this.outerHeight());
    let divWidth = parseFloat($this.outerWidth());
    let className = "";
    //check if child div's width is greater then height then add some class
    className = divWidth > divHeight ? 'class1' : 'class2';
    if (divWidth === divHeight)
        className = 'class3';
    $this.removeClass('class1').removeClass('class2').removeClass('class3').addClass(className);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* ---- grid ---- */

h1 {
  text-align: center
}

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.class1 { background-color: red; }
.class2 { background-color: blue; }
.class3 { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - masonry layout mode</h1>
<div class="grid" >
  <div class="grid-item" style="height:200px;width:200px;" >
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="height:203px;width:201px;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x500.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solutions is working fine. Thanks for your effort bro:). But here you gave static height and width.while my images will comes dynamic from database. That time its add "class1" to all child div

Comment: @HimanshuVaghela I gave static Height and widht for demo only, but it exactly works even your Height and Width value come from database too, you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: I tried it in my codepen. Please check here.

https://codepen.io/manshu07/pen/oNgyzrr


Its add class3 in all child div

Comment: @HimanshuVaghela https://codepen.io/shoesheill/pen/YzPvpKP check this it's working fine.

Comment: Sorry bro. Here latest codepen. I forget to update latest.https://codepen.io/manshu07/pen/oNgyzrr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205854/discussion-between-himanshu-vaghela-and-sushil).

Comment: update `let divHeight = parseFloat($this.find('img').outerHeight());
    let divWidth = parseFloat($this.find('img').outerWidth());` and it works

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$('.grid').children().each(function(item) {` use `$('.grid-item').each(function(item) {` and find element by `$(this).height()` and `width()`

```js
$('.grid-item').each(function(item) {
  let divHeight = 0;
  let divWidth = 0;
  divHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
  divWidth = $(this).find('img').width();

  if (divWidth > divHeight) {
    $(this).addClass('class1');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* ---- grid ---- */

h1 {
  text-align: center
}

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.class1 {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - masonry layout mode</h1>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment, you should get width and height of your image, not your div, of course in this example!

Comment: I tried this solution but its add class in all div which is not greater then in height

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to be more specific - you want to inspect the IMAGE in the div since the divs are all the same width

```js
$(function() {
  $('.grid .grid-item').each(function() {
    var imgHeight = $(this).find("img").height();
    var imgWidth  = $(this).find("img").width();

    //check if child div's width is greater then height then add some class
    console.log(imgHeight, imgWidth, imgHeight> imgWidth)
    $(this).toggleClass('class1',imgHeight > imgWidth);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* ---- grid ---- */

h1 {
  text-align: center
}

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.class1 { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - masonry layout mode</h1>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x500.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but its not add class if height is greater then width.

Comment: Thanks Man!! I'm not sure why its not works in my code. let me try again.